# React JS: Uncaught TypeError: getState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a simple API call to the server. To make it I have created a file named - `likes.js`, inside it I have:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import tokenConfig from './auth';

// Like Report
export const likePostas = (report_public_id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  console.log('Trying to call the server')
  axios
    .post(`/api/report/like?report=${report_public_id}`, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.response.data)
    });
};
```

So basically it should be working, the other thing is that I need to pass in the token to the headers, so I have another file for that which is `auth.js`

```
// Setup config with token - helper function
export const tokenConfig = (getState) => {
  // Get token from state
  const token = getState().auth.token;

  // Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  // If token, add to headers config
  if (token) {
    config.headers['Authorization'] = `Token ${token}`;
  }

  return config;
};

export default tokenConfig;
```

Now I need to just call it by pressing a button inside JSX.
Here's my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "../ButtonElement";
import { likePostas } from "../actions/likes";


const ReportCards = ({ report }) => {
  const IsVerifiedDiv = (
    <IsVerified>
      <GoVerified />
      <IsVerifiedToolTip>
        This user is <span style={{ color: "#01BF71" }}>Verified</span>
      </IsVerifiedToolTip>
    </IsVerified>
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    document.title = `Winteka - View Report`;
    window.scroll({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  }, [0]);

  return (
    <>
        <BtnWrap2 onClick={likePostas(report.public_id)} />
    </>
  );
};

export default ReportCards;
```

But as I press the button I get this error:

```
react-dom.development.js:327 Uncaught TypeError: getState is not a function
```

Comment: How are you handling the `onClick` inside your `BtnWrap2` component? That's where it needs to be called with the right arguments, can you show that part

Comment: After changing it to `onClick={() => likePostas(report.public_id)}` when I click the button, nothing happens.

Comment: @Jayce444 I have a lot of JSX code, so I just left this to show how I try to call the API

Comment: Are you using `redux` and `redux-thunk`? Is `likePostas` an async action creator?

Comment: @Yousaf You see, I'm really green on React, for now, I think that's redux. I did it by a tutorial on Yt.

Comment: I understand that you're new and you have lots of code, but the relevant code is missing from your question so we can't help you. We need to see how you handle `onClick` inside the `BtnWrap2` component, whether you're connecting it to Redux properly, cos that's how it would normally get that second parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using `react-redux` and `redux-thunk` and `likePostas` is an async action creator.

Instead of calling `likePostas` action creator yourself, you need to let `react-redux` call it with the values for the two parameters that it takes, i.e. `dispatch` and `getState`. Currently the problem is that as you are calling `likePostas` action creator yourself, `dispatch` and `getState` are undefined because you never pass those arguments to the function returned by `likePostas`.

#### Solution

Add an `onClick` listener on `BtnWrap2` that will dispatch `likePostas` action creator.

Import the `useDispatch` hook from the `react-redux` package.

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
```

then use this `useDispatch` hook to dispatch the `likePostas` action when the button is clicked.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const handleClick = (id) => {
   dispatch(likePostas(id));
};
```

and add this `handleClick` an a click listener on the `BtnWrap2` component.

```
<BtnWrap2 onClick={() => handleClick(report.public_id)} />
```

I suggest that you visit the following links to learn how to use `react-redux` and `redux-thunk`:

- [`react-redux`](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start)
- [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)

Comment: But as I can see in the back-end the request is not providing the token for authorization

Comment: https://gyazo.com/1e77a28889e5d9fe4295f59bed7b468e yes, there is

Comment: auth > token > "e2ea99424e12f6f3fc9e4fcaf3bbf7a84a7f82a8fc82ef421f1f5c37f0c58878"

Comment: Try to log `getState().auth.token` and see what you get on the console

Comment: But why do I get "Authentication credentials were not provided." if the token is being passed?

Comment: That response is from the server-side code, so you need to look at that code and see how it expects to receive the token